# Scipy sparse matrix assignment using only stored elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix globalGrid (lil_matrix) and a smaller matrix localGrid (coo_matrix). The localGrid represents a subset of the globalGrid and I want to update the globalGrid with the localGrid. For this I use the following code (in Python Scipy):

```
globalGrid[xLocalgrid:xLocalgrid + localGrid.shape[0], yLocalgrid: yLocalgrid + localGrid.shape[1]] = localGrid
```

where xLocalGrid and yLocalGrid are the offset of the localGrid origin with respect to the globalGrid.

The problem is that the localGrid is sparse, but also the zero elements are assigned to the globalGrid. Is there a way I can only assign the stored elements and not the 0-elements?

I have found about masked arrays in numpy, however that does not seem to apply to sparse scipy matrices.

edit: In response to the comments below, here is a example to illustrate what I mean:

First setup the matrices:

```
M=sparse.lil_matrix(2*np.ones([5,5]))
m = sparse.eye(3)

M.todense()
matrix([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])

m.todense()
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Then assign:

```
M[1:4, 1:4] = m
```

Now the result is:

```
M.todense()
matrix([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Whereas I need the result to be:

```
matrix([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Does this assignment work, with correct values in `globalGrid`? Are you worried that there are unnecessary 0 terms in the result? Do you see those I its `.data` attribute?  You may need to show example matrices.

Comment: Could you give us a [mcve] and the exact expected output?

Comment: I have added an example of what I want to achieve to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should this line

> The problem is that the localGrid is sparse, but also the non-zero elements are assigned to the globalGrid. Is there a way I can only assign the stored elements and not the 0-elements?

be changed to?

> The problem is that the localGrid is sparse, but also the **zero** elements are assigned to the globalGrid. Is there a way I can only assign the stored elements and not the 0-elements?

Your question isn't quite clear, but I'm guessing that because the `globalGrid[a:b, c:d]` indexing spans values that should be 0 in both arrays, that you are worried that 0's are being copied.

Let's try this with real matrices.

```
In [13]: M=sparse.lil_matrix((10,10))
In [14]: m=sparse.eye(3)
In [15]: M[4:7,5:8]=m
In [16]: m
Out[16]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [17]: M
Out[17]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [18]: M.data
Out[18]: array([[], [], [], [], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [], [], []], dtype=object)
In [19]: M.rows
Out[19]: array([[], [], [], [], [5], [6], [7], [], [], []], dtype=object)
```

`M` does not have any unnecessary 0's.

If there are unnecessary 0's in a sparse matrix, a round trip to `csr` format should take care of them

```
M.tocsr().tolil()
```

`csr` format also has an inplace `.eliminate_zeros()` method.

---

So your concern is with over writing the nonzeros of the target array.

With dense arrays, the use of `nonzero` (or `where`) takes care of this:

```
In [87]: X=np.ones((10,10),int)*2
In [88]: y=np.eye(3)
In [89]: I,J=np.nonzero(y)
In [90]: X[I+3,J+2]=y[I,J]
In [91]: X
Out[91]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Trying the sparse equivalent:

```
In [92]: M=sparse.lil_matrix(X)
In [93]: M
Out[93]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 100 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [94]: m=sparse.coo_matrix(y)
In [95]: m
Out[95]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [96]: I,J=np.nonzero(m)
In [97]: I
Out[97]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [98]: J
Out[98]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [99]: M[I+3,J+2]=m[I,J]
...
TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

I could have used the sparse matrix own `nonzero`.

```
In [106]: I,J=m.nonzero()
```

For `coo` format, this is the same as

```
In [109]: I,J=m.row, m.col
```

In which case I can also use the `data` attribute:

```
In [100]: M[I+3,J+2]=m.data
In [101]: M.A
Out[101]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

The code for `m.nonzero` may be instructive

```
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask],A.col[nz_mask])
```

So you need to be careful to make sure that index and data attributes of the sparse matrix match.

And also pay attention as to which sparse formats allow indexing.  `lil` is good for changing values.  `csr` allows element by element indexing, but raises an efficiency warning if you try to change zero values to nonzero (or v.v.).  `coo` has this nice pairing of indices and data, but doesn't allow indexing.

Another subtle point: in constructing a `coo` you may repeat coordinates.  When converted to `csr` format those values are summed.  But the assignment that I'm suggesting will only use the last value, not the sum.  So make sure you understand how your `local` matrix was constructed, and know whether it is a 'clean' representation of the data.

Comment: The change you suggest is right. I've edited the question accordingly.

You're answer does not apply to what I want. I've edited the question and added an example to make my desire more clear.

Comment: So you are concerned about the zeros overwriting nonzeros in the `global`.  Then you need to use some version of `nonzero` indexing.  Try it with dense, and see what works with sparse.

Comment: See my edits for the use of `nonzero` to index the insertion points.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it works and it's simple.

However, the approach I posted below is about 30% faster on my (small) test case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution. Instead of using an assignment I loop over the data in the sparse matrix (using M.data and M.rows) and replace the elements one by one.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(m.rows):
    for idy, col in enumerate(row):
        M[yOffset+col, xOffset+idx] = m.data[idx][idy]
```

I am still curious though if there is no simpler/faster method to achieve this result.

My implementation of the above answer:

```
I,J = m.nonzero()
M[I+yOffset,J+xOffset] = m[I,J]
return M'
```

This was however marginally slower.