# SciPy Sparse Matrix: How to Remove an Element from Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

What is the most efficient way to remove a single non-zero element from a SciPy sparse matrix? For example, if I have the following:

```
A = csr_matrix((2, 2))
A[1, 1] = 1
print(A.A)
```

Which gives a matrix with all 0s and one 1 at position (0,0), how can I remove that 1 and reset it to a zero? Here is a naive approach that works:

```
A[1, 1] = 0
A.eliminate_zeros()
```

But there must be a better way...

Comment: That's essentially the way to do it.  You could change the `A.data[:]=0` array directly, but you still need `eliminate_zeros` to change the sparsity structure.   Making a new array by `*0` doesn't change sparsity either.  For sake of efficiency it doesn't change sparsity every time values are changed (to 0).  Changing zeros to nonzero does change sparsity, and it gives you a warning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674435/scipy-sparse-matrix-become-dense-matrix-after-assignment; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505416/efficient-way-to-set-elements-to-zero-where-mask-is-true-on-scipy-sparse-matrix; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719588/scipy-sparse-matrix-assignment-using-only-stored-elements